# 3-month and 12-month Moving Average by Customer in R

Tags: r

fairly new to R and have a question re: moving average/rolling mean

I have a table that looks like this in R:

```
CustomerID | ProductID | FiscalPeriod | Volume  | GP
ABC123        987654     January 2013   $10,000  $3,000
ABC123        987654     February 2013  $500     $200   
ABC123        987654     March 2013     $6,000   $2,000
XYZ555        123456     January 2013   $550     $150
XYZ555        123456     February 2013  $4,000   $800
...
```

Each customer/product combination has a FiscalPeriod Volume/GP value (even if it's zero).

Ultimately, I'd like an output that looks like:

```
CustomerID | ProductID | 3MthMovAvgVol| 12MthMovAvgVol| 3MthMovAvgGP | 12MthMovAvgGP
ABC123       987654      $7,500         $8,250          $1,750         $1,950
XYZ555       123456      $3,500         $4,650          $600           $800
```

The goal is to have a 3m/12m moving average/rolling mean for both volume and GP by customer and product combination.

I've been looking at zoo and ttr but can't seem to get anywhere on how to execute on this.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can you have a moving average if your output doesn't include a date? I.e. your `3MthMovAvgVol` column is 3 months from _when_?

Comment: The output columns would be from the most recent completed period. For example, if I ran this today the outputs would be as of close of business in August.

Comment: Then it's not a moving average. It's just an average of the last X periods in the data set.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense (re: the 12 mth piece). So how would I go about creating an output such as the desired one above incorporating just the mean of the previous 12 months along with the 3MthMovAvg grouped by CustomerID/ProductID?

Answer (score 0):

```
## You can use odbc package.For example, you put data in d:/test.xls.
install.packages('RODBC')
library('RODBC')
channel=odbcConnectExcel("d:/test.xls")
## I do not know what 3-months moving average means, you can set conditions using "where" in this SQL below
sqlQuery(channel,'select  a.CustomerID,a.avgVol_12, a.avgGP_12 , b.AvgVol_3 ,b.AvgGP_3   from 
(select CustomerID,sum(Volume)/12 as  avgVol_12,sum(GP)/12 as avgGP_12 from [Sheet1$] group by CustomerID) a  
left outer  join  
(select CustomerID,sum(Volume)/3 as AvgVol_3, sum(GP)/3 as AvgGP_3  from [Sheet1$] where month(FiscalPeriod)>=3 group by CustomerID ) b  
on a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID  ' )
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra work and potential for errors, when you could simply use the [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/package=sqldf) package.

Comment: Thanks Josh...so would the sqldf route be what you recommend I explore to accomplish this?